# How to add an integer value from a variable to an auto-incremental primary key field in a MySQL database?

Tags: java, mysql

Here is what I vainly tried to do:

```
        int x = 0;

        PreparedStatement ps;
        String query = "INSERT INTO staff VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)"; 

        try {
            
            ps = ConnectDb.getConnection().prepareStatement(query);
            x++;

            //ps.setInt(1, x);
            ps.setString(2, nameTxt.getText());  
            ps.setString(3, emailTxt.getText());
            ps.setString(4, address.getText());  
            ps.setString(5, phone.getText());  
            ps.setString(6, genderCb.getSelectedItem().toString());
            
            ps.execute();
            
            if (x > 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Staff added successfully");
            }

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex,"Error: Staff not added!",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                 frm.setVisible(true);
            }

        }

    }
```

How can I continuously add record to the database without getting any exception on the auto-incremental primary key (e.g StaffID)?

Comment: please [edit] and share the full exception. Also share the table definition

Comment: As I remember it said "Duplicate entry '1'for key 'PRIMARY'".
Sorry but I've deleted the table from my database.

Answer (score 0):

Create a sequence in database and pass that sequence name in insert query.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you anyway, I solved it by removing the x variable and the first parameter in my query.